# Cyclic queue with full BUFFER capacity

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, queue

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
typedef {
...
} item;

item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
```

buffer is empty when

```
in == out
```

buffer is full when

```
((in+1)%BUFFER_SIZE) == out
```

This algorithm allows at most `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` item in the buffer at the same time.

Is there a solution where `BUFFER_SIZE` items can be in the buffer at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an integer variable counter, initialized to 0. Counter is incremented every time we add a new item to the buffer and is decremented every time we remove one item from the buffer.

Producer -

```js
while (true) {
  /* produce an item in nextProduced */ 
  while (counter == BUFFER_SIZE)
  ; /* do nothing */ 
  buffer[in] = nextProduced; 
  in = (in + 1) %BUFFER_SIZE; 
  counter++;
}
```

Consumer -

```js
while (true) {
  while (counter == 0)
  ; /* do nothing */
  nextConsumed = buffer[out];
  out = (out + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE; 
  counter--;
  /* consume the item in nextConsumed */
}
```